# How to align jQuery div to bottom left corner using CSS?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

```
.ui-dialog { position: absolute; padding: .2em; width: 300px; overflow: hidden; }
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar { padding: .4em 1em; position: relative;  }
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title { float: left; margin: .1em 16px .1em 0; } 
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close { position: absolute; right: .3em; top: 50%; width: 19px; margin: -10px 0 0 0; padding: 1px; height: 18px; }
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close span { display: block; margin: 1px; }
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close:hover, .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close:focus { padding: 0; }
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content { position: relative; border: 0; padding: .5em 1em; background: none; overflow: auto; zoom: 1; }
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane { text-align: left; border-width: 1px 0 0 0; background-image: none; margin: 1000 0 0 0; padding: .3em 1em .5em .4em; }
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset { float: right; }
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane button { margin: .5em .4em .5em 0; cursor: pointer; }
.ui-dialog .ui-resizable-se { width: 14px; height: 14px; right: 3px; bottom: 3px; }
.ui-draggable .ui-dialog-titlebar { cursor: move; }
```

I am using Jquery modal popup . All time when i try to open it on my asp.net page it shows in center but i want to open it in botton left . Tried and found no solution .

this is what i have done in Jquery :

```
$j(function() {
    $j("#dialog").dialog({
        title: "Warning",
        buttons: {}
    });
});

<div id="dialog" style="display: none;left:0;bottom:0;">
    * Invalid Username
</div>
```

I want to align the div with dialog in bottom left corner . How to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: that's not a "jquery div". it's a div you happen to manipulating with jquery. just because you're using jquery doesn't make it any magically different - you'd position it like you would any other div... write the appropriate css.

Comment: Marc this is not a homework question i am asking to you . I have asked it because found no solution . The css i used before is in style of div left:0;bottom:0 also i have tried to keep the div inside another div and apply the above css to that but it dosent works. Please if you can ...provide an answer . thanks for help.

Comment: I didn't say it was a homework question. But this is no different than any other css positioning problem.

Comment: Try this one `<div id="dialog" style="bottom:0;position:absolute;" >`

Comment: @Rambo_Raja  [Here](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position) is the API documentation for dialog position. Please try which ever you need. Thanks.

Comment: I have used this only brother. thnk u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$j(function() {
    $j("#dialog").dialog({
        title: "Warning",
        position: [0, 600],
        buttons: {}
    });
});
```

By writing position:[0,600] I solved it .